# Forcing www on all URLs without htaccess

Tags: django, apache, redirect, mod-wsgi

I have a complex setup wherein am having Django 3 sub-projects kind of thing hosted on single Apache via mod wsgi.

I want to have www prepended on all addresses for one of these as some payment gateways are behaving improper without www URLs. Now, .htaccess's canonical redirect messes up the other 2. Using PREPEND_WWW from common middleware works only for foo.jp and not for foo.jp/bar/* and so on...

Similarly, I also tried to create an index.php, pointed to it from sites-enabled in apache and used header redirection to www.foo.jp for foo.jp...

Please tell me a way for all URLs i.e. anything foo.jp/*, foo.jp/bar/* etc. to www.foo.jp/*, www.foo.jp/bar/* and so on...

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out...

In the apache/sites-enabled/000-default

Basically, the default apache virtual host file which is read before other domain's virtual host files I added this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName playism.jp
    Redirect permanent / http://www.foo.jp/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, it is redirecting for everything... without the .htaccess which was messing it up !